# Naming foreign key column

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I defined those 2 tables:

```
[Table("languages")]
public class Language
{
    [Key]
    [Column("language_id")]
    public int LCID { get; set; }
    [Column("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Column("enabled")]
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    [Column("default")]
    public bool Default { get; set; }
}
[Table("localized_content")]
public class LocalizedContent
{
    [Key]
    [Column("content_id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column("language_id")]
    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
    [Column("content")]
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

In the LocalizedContent class, I want column to be created with name as defined in column attribute, but EF ignores it, and creates tolumn named Language_LCID:

[image]

How can I force it to be named language_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this you will have to define another key of type the primary key of Language which is int and mark it as `Foreign Key`

```
[Table("localized_content")]
public class LocalizedContent
{
    [Key]
    [Column("content_id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LanguageId")]
    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("language_id")]
    public int LanguageId{get; set;}
    [Column("content")]
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! One fix thought - the Key attribute should remain on Language property, otherwise it gives error: Unable to determine composite primary key ordering...